# PG::Connection.ping fails with - Symbol not found: _PQping

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pg, postgresql-9.6

I was getting this error on Postgres 9.4.1:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQping
  Referenced from: <home_dir>/.rbenv/versions/2.4.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

`/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib` is linked to `postgresql@9.6` version

`/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib -> ../Cellar/postgresql@9.6/9.6.5/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

And then, I upgraded to 9.6.5 using:

```
brew install/upgrade
```

but still getting the error. The `pg` gem looks ok, I can connect from my Rails app and query my models.

How do I fix the error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. So, how do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$ gem uninstall pg` and then `$ bundle install`